# Issues with loading images in production mode with reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing a reactjs app and in development mode everything is okey  with images

```
<img src={`/images/logo.jpg`}></img>
```

But when I want to deploy my app using `npm run build` I tried to use environnement variable `PUBLIC_URL` but i have issues with loading images (js & css are loaded correctly)

```
<img src={`/${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/logo.jpg`}></img>
```

I read that the value of `PUBLIC_URL` can be set in **package.json** properties `homepage` (i am using `create-react-app`)

```
  "homepage": "https://localhost:8080/FOO-API/REACT-APP/",
```

When i try to print its value

```
console.log('public url : ', process.env.PUBLIC_URL)
```

I got the right path `public url :  /PROJET-API/REACT-APP`

But the image does not shows up and its URL is wrong

`http://foo-api/REACT-APP/images/logo.jpg`

the `https://localhost:8080/` part is gone and `FOO-API` is converted to lowercase

the URL should be `https://localhost:8080/FOO-API/REACT-APP/images/logo.jpg`

Comment: Hi Youssef,check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is first `/` here,

```
<img src={`/${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/logo.jpg`}></img>
```

As you can see, the result of `console.log`

```
console.log('public url : ', process.env.PUBLIC_URL)
```

is,

```
public url :  /PROJET-API/REACT-APP
```

Which alreay contains `/` at the beginning.

So your URL is created as,

```
<img src={`//PROJET-API/REACT-APP/images/logo.jpg`}></img>
```

Notice that it contains `2` `/` at the beginning.

You just need to remove the `/` from beginning, like:

```
<img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/logo.jpg`}></img>
```